# javascript version of enter_frame from as3

Tags: javascript

In action script 3 I know how to animate a graphic from one side of the screen to the other with an enter frame event. I'm trying to do the same thing with a div tag threw javascript.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: @JonathandeM. What is the jQuery Solution ?

Comment: `$('div').animate({right:0})` with a position absolute on the `div`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to imitate enterframe in as3, you can see how to do it here [JavaScript's version of ActionScript's Event.ENTER_FRAME event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615064/javascripts-version-of-actionscripts-event-enter-frame-event)